# Downloading using webview android?

Tags: android, android-webview

Is there any permission to be set in android manifest to download a file/document using webview?

I'm trying to display a button using webview, when the button is clicked, a file should be downloaded and saved in the device.

This permission is given:

```
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`
```

This piece of code loads the page which contains button in it:

```
storeLocator = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.storeLocator);
    storeLocator.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    storeLocator.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    // storeLocator.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    storeLocator.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
            progressDialog.show();
            progressDialog.setProgress(0);
            activity.setProgress(progress * 1000);

            progressDialog.incrementProgressBy(progress);

            if (progress == 100 && progressDialog.isShowing())
                progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    storeLocator.loadUrl(getResources().getString(R.string.home));
```

Comment: Could you please give further detail? What error are you getting? If you're sure it's a permission problem (android.permission.INTERNET, maybe?) Logcat usually has relevant information!

Comment: @Carlos I'm not getting any error. On click of the button no action is being performed!! Internet permission is given.

Comment: In that case, maybe posting some code would be useful? :)

Comment: @Carlos that module is added :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This module is the answer:

```
storeLocator.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
                public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                        String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                        long contentLength) {
                  Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                  i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                  startActivity(i);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to implement? Try using a standard button and on it's onclick you will have to download the file yourself.

Comment: I'm trying to display a page which is hosted in some other server, there is a contract doc which has to be downloaded on click of button present in that page